# Is server fault an appropriate forum for this modem-related question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I want to ask a question, but I'm not sure if server fault is the correct place for the question. Here is a rough draft of the question:

> Is it possible to use two modems with the intention of speeding up my
>   AT&T 'DSL Lite' connection by augmenting it with my Cel-Phone's
>   tethered 'hot spot' connection (which I sometimes use temporarily for
>   faster service). ATT's hot spot is considerably faster than my DSL
>   Lite connection, but is too expensive to use daily. My current
>   thinking is that some software probably exists that makes it possible
>   to use the cheapest bandwidth first (ATT DSL Lite) and leave it on
>   (always flowing) but when the connection pauses/waits/bottlenecks/etc.
>   it would then use the more expensive, but quicker bandwidth from my
>   tethered cel phone. I don't remember the details of TCP and UDP, but
>   the solution should work with both webpages and streaming data,
>   especially YouTube videos.

Is ServerFault an appropriate place to ask this sort of question? If not, which Stack Exchange site would be most appropriate for this sort of question?

Comment: This question appears likely to fail the "managing information technology systems in a business environment" test, that is, our very topic.

Comment: Yes,  @Michael Hampton ,  I think your right. I looked again at the various sites on stackexchange and I think 'Software Recommendations'
("Q&A for people seeking specific software recommendations") is an appropriate forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael indicated probably not in topic on ServerFault as IMHO you phrase it as an end-user problem and appear to be thinking towards an single user solution as well. [SuperUser](http://superUser.com) might be suitable. The other thing is it might be seen as an off-topic product recommendation question.

A business solution would be more towards a router that supports multiple uplinks, one of which could be a 3g/4G WWAN network uplink, not uncommon. Some vendor background [here](http://www.draytek.co.uk/information/our-technology/3g-solutions)